# How to remove spring tube of Forious faucet?

Tags: faucet

How to remove spring tube of Forious faucet ? Existing faucet was newly assembled. I want to **undo** step 1.

Instructions: https://imgur.com/a/pPHaYrR

Comment: Why don't you just reverse the process? Unfortunately, imgur is down atm, so we can't see the pics.

Comment: Step 1 cannot be reversed. There is some other thing in it